# Parse all presented USB devices in Linux OS by specified VID and PID and put it to structure (C, not C++)?

Tags: linux, parsing, usb, pid

I want to put to a structure all USB devices meeting of specified VID and PID presented in a Linux OS.

So, I got some code from usbreset and some other soft and tried to modify under my task.

As a result:
there is a structure

```
struct usbdevices {
    struct usbdevice *device;
    int index;
};
```

struct usbdevice - defined in Linux headers;

there is functional code:

```
struct usbdevices *find_devices_by_dvid_dpid(int *vid, int *pid) {

    struct usbdevices *devices = malloc(sizeof(struct usbdevices));
    devices->device = NULL;

    struct usbdevice *e = NULL, *tmp = NULL;

    int index = 1;

    DIR *devs = opendir(sys_device);

    if (!devs)
        return NULL;

    while ((e = parse_devlist(devs)) != NULL) {
            tmp = realloc(devices->device, index * sizeof(struct usbdevice));
            if (tmp == NULL) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error reallocating memory !\n");
                free(devices->device);
                return NULL;
            } else {
                devices->device = tmp;

                memcpy(&devices->device[((index - 1) * sizeof(struct usbdevice))], e, sizeof(struct usbdevice));

                devices->index = index;
            }
        }

        index ++;
        tmp = NULL;
        free(tmp);
    }

    closedir(devs);

    return devices;
}
```

But only first and last USB devices are put to structure.

If use initially and only malloc without realloc at all for, for example 7 devices (index = 7) as:

```
devices->device = malloc(7 * sizeof(struct usbdevice));
```

all works fine.
But USB devices with specified VID/PID can be less or more in the system and it is unknown its numbers during malloc asignment.

More over, I saw memory allocation size depending of USB order number.
The size of usbdevice structure are 104 bytes; for the first device 104 bytes are allocated by realloc, for second - not 208, but 216 bytes are allocated, what do not corresond to index * 104, for third are 312 (it is 104 * 3) and for other USB devices memory allocation corresponds index (USB device order number) * 104.

What is wrong ?
Is there much better way to reach given task for Linux on C ?